# How to map an array of integers to have a key and value format?

Tags: ruby

Having the following sample input:

```json
{
    "array": [
        {
            "userId": 1203746,
            "leadContactVids": [
                68310280,
                68310253
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get it to the following format:

```json
{
    "updatedArray": [
        {
            "userId": 1203746,
            "leadContactVids": [
                {
                "id": 68310280,
                "id": 68310253
                                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to use the following ruby code but it's returning the initial format, and not the one that includes the key "id":

```
updatedArray= array.each do |entry|
    qlIds = entry.dig(:leadContactVids)&.map { |item| {id: item} }
    entry.merge({
      leadContactVids: qlIds
    })
end
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, so I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: You cannot have `{ "id": 68310280, "id": 68310253 }` as a hash's keys must be unique. Please edit to correct your desired result. Also, when you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to all input values (here there is just one, your hash). That way readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. You could write, say, `h = { "array": [....] }`.

Answer (score 2):

I would create new arrays from the existing array and replace their data format with ['Array#map'](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Array.html#method-i-map)  to the expected new format:

```
input = {
  "array": [
    {
      "userId": 1203746,
      "leadContactVids": [68310280, 68310253]
    }
  ]
}

output = {
  updatedArray: input[:array].map { |elem| 
    {
      userId: elem[:userId],
      leadContactVids: elem[:leadContactVids].map { |id| { id: id } }
    }
  }
}
#=> {:updatedArray=>[{:userId=>1203746, :leadContactVids=>[{:id=>68310280}, {:id=>68310253}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

as @spickermann said, you should use `#map` to get the returned value, rather than `#each`, as the "array" object isn't being changed:

**setup**

```
array = [
  {
    "userId": 1203746,
    "leadContactVids": [
      68310280, 68310253
    ]
  }
]
 => [{:userId=>1203746, :leadContactVids=>[68310280, 68310253]}]
```

**fixed code**

```
updatedArray= array.map do |entry|
  qlIds = entry.dig(:leadContactVids)&.map { |item| {id: item} }
  entry.merge({
      leadContactVids: qlIds
      })
end
 => [{:userId=>1203746, :leadContactVids=>[{:id=>68310280}, {:id=>68310253}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

We are given the following hash.

```
h = {
  "array": [
    {
      "userId": 1203746,
      "leadContactVids": [
        68310280,
        68310253
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The desired hash can be obtained as follows.

```
{ updatedArray: [
    h[:array].first.transform_values do |v|
      case v
      when Array
        v.map { |n| { id: n } }
      else
        v
      end
    end
  ]
}
  #=> {
  #     :updatedArray=>[
  #       {
  #         :userId=>1203746,
  #         :leadContactVids=>[
  #           {:id=>68310280},
  #           {:id=>68310253}
  #         ]
  #       }
  #     ]
  #   }
```

I assume this is the result you want. See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values). The original hash is not mutated.